# Entity Framework, DbSet<T>, Dispose() performance questions

Tags: entity-framework, linq, dispose

This is my first post :) I'm new to MVC .NET. And have some questions in regards to Entity Framework functionality and performance. Questions inline...

```
class StudentContext : DbContext
{
    public StudentContext() : base("myconnectionstring") {};
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Question: Does DbSet read all the records from the database Student table, and store it in collection Students (i.e. in memory)? Or does it simply hold a connection to this table, and (record) fetches are done at the time SQL is executed against the database?

For the following:

```
private StudentContext db = new StudentContext();
Student astudent = db.Students.Find(id);
```

or

```
var astudent = from s in db.Students
               where s.StudentID == id)
               select s;
```

Question: Which of these are better for performance? I'm not sure how the Find method works under-the-hood for a collection?

Question: When are database connections closed? During the Dispose() method call?
If so, should I call the Dispose() method for a class that has the database context instance? I've read here to use Using blocks.

I'm guessing for a Controller class get's instantiated, does work including database access, calls it's associated View, and then (the Controller) gets out of scope and is unloaded from memory. Or the garbase collector. But best call Dispose() to do cleanup explicitly.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `DbSet<T>` means you use Entity Framework, not LINQ to SQL, don't you?

Comment: Yes, using EF. Sorry, new to these terms. I should have said EF and LINQ statements.

Comment: OK, I've edited your question to match that.

Comment: Re my second question, the terms which I've now learnt are LINQ Query syntax and Method Syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Find` method looks in the DbContext for an entity which has the specified key(s). If there is no matching entity already loaded, the DbContext will makes a `SELECT TOP 1` query to get the entity.

Running `db.Students.Where(s => s.StudentID == id)` will get you a sequence containing all the entities returned from a SQL query similar to `SELECT * FROM Students WHERE StudentID = @id`. That should be pretty fast; you can speed it up by using `db.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == id)`, which adds a `TOP 1` to the SQL query.

Using `Find` is more efficient if you're loading the same entity more than once from the same DbContext. Other than that `Find` and `FirstOrDefault` are pretty much equivalent.

In neither case does the context load the entire table, nor does it hold *open* a connection. I believe the DbContext holds a connection until the DbContext is disposed, but it opens and closes the connection on demand when it needs to resolve a query.

Comment: Yes, thanks. And from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx   The Entity Framework opens connections only when required, for example to execute a query or to call SaveChanges, and then closes the connection when the operation is complete.
Calling any of the following methods opens the connection: 1. SaveChanges or Refresh on ObjectContext. 2. FirstOrDefault, or First on ObjectQuery. 3. Load on EntityCollection. 4. Load on EntityReference. 5. Any Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) method or ObjectQuery query builder method, such as Where, OrderBy, or Select.

Comment: Number 5 on that list is not correct; the connection is definitely only opened when the IQueryable is *enumerated*, not when the query method is called.